# How to configure Jacoco Code Coverage for Web application

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I have a web application with module based architecture. Application have around thousand of files, now we need to implement code coverage using **Jacoco**.

Technology Used in web application -

Spring, Hibernate, Ext.js, Mysql, Jersy, Tomcat 7.0.96, Maven

I don't want to write any Junit, functional, integration test, means nothing more changes in code side regarding to code coverage.

Tried Solutions -

Found some solutions -

1. Place Jacoco jar files in tomcat
2. Configure setenv.sh to point jacoc jar
3. Restart server
4. When Server are stopped jacoco.exec file will be generated.
5. Place pom.xml and web package in target folder
6. execute mvn jacoco:report

But unable to find setev.sh or setev.bat file inside tomcat 7.0.96, I tried same configuration inside catalina.bat but jacoco.exec file not generated.

also refer URL -

http://crc83.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-mesure-code-coverage-on-tomcat.html
http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html

but unable to connect and getting error.

Error while loading coverage session (code 5001).

Error while connecting to JaCoCo agent at address 127.0.0.1 on port 6300 (code 5006).

Connection refused: connect

Please suggest me some solution with min changes, so I will implement and check my application code coverage.

Comment: Do you have unit tests in your code base?

Comment: is your plan to start the application and measure what code is covered by clicking around or running a ui test tool? Or do you plan to measure coverage during the build process?

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is no test cases in code base and there is no plan to right test cases. in code base. May be in build process if we want to measure coverage then we need to right some test case.
Apart from that is there is any solution thorough which I can check code coverage with minimum code changes, So I am not much aware about it.